# How do I retrieve a specific information on firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android programming and wish to explore more on Android programming. My current database tree looks like this [image: database tree strucutre] and this is how I push the data into the database [image: push info into database].

Can any professional teach me on how to retrieve a specific data (e.g. name / phone number) from a specific user in the user list and display them?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
After trying several solutions, the only code that can retrieve the name is this

`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("-MA5f3qb0nBBTkViv-pz");`

I even tried to assign the UID to a string and put in into the second child like this 
`String UID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();`

But the code will not run too with the error of "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve information try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   User userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
 });
```

Add a reference to node `User` and then using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` you can retrieve the values.

Comment: reference to node "User", surely?

Comment: added an "s" in the explanation but in the code its without an "s" :p @deworde

Comment: @PeterHaddad

Dear Peter, I've tried to replicate your code and tried to send value to textView_userName but the textView section will remain empty. Here is the section of code.

`public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                textViewUserName.setText(user.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });`

Please enlighten me on that?

Comment: @JulianaLam in your class `Users` do you have an empty constructor?

Comment: @PeterHaddad

Ya, i had them

Comment: @JulianaLam add a breakpoint and check what are you retrieving